# files list file for package 'libvo-aacenc0:amd64' is missing final newline

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have a problem with dpkg when I try to install any package.

Here is log output:

```
➜  LC_MESSAGES=C sudo apt install tree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/40,6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 138 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package tree.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libvo-aacenc0:amd64' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
➜
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libvo-aacenc0*
sudo apt-get install libvo-aacenc0 --reinstall
```

Comment: Any ideas how the error occurred in the first place?

Comment: The file got corrupted, plenty of reasons for that to happen.