# Dpkg unrecoverable fatal error

Tags: dpkg

I'm getting this following error while I'm trying to install or uninstall any file. I have tried almost every solution I found on internet but still showing the same error.

Please do not say to install ubuntu again. I have lots of files which cannot be retrieved easily.

error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'avahi-autoipd' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I'm also getting so many warning related to dpkg:

eg:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-firmware' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package
```

i have tried the following

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux* ./
mv: cannot stat '/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux*': No such file or directory

sudo apt-get update ---- works fine
sudo apt-get upgrade ---- gives dpkg error(above)

Comment: Seems like an exact duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/430682/dpkg-warning-files-list-file-for-package-x-missing. Since this is likely among the "tried almost every solution," please edit your question to show us exactly how these solutions failed.

Comment: You haven't I feel provided the actual error message, only the summary which is a clue to look up the report to find what caused the error code reported by calling program. We can't help when we can't see your actual problems (only the end-summary)

Comment: maneela@ubuntu:~$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux* ./
mv: cannot stat '/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux*': No such file or directory
maneela@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
maneela@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update these two worked well...  error has occurred during              sudo apt upgrade ... error is same as above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg is crashing on Ubuntu 16.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878973/dpkg-is-crashing-on-ubuntu-16-04-1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package 'linux-generic' is missing final newline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909719/dpkg-unrecoverable-fatal-error-aborting-files-list-file-for-package-linux-ge)