# Ubuntu 20.04 update problem

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

When I try to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` the following error occurs, the system is not working properly, and I am not able to update or install any software.

Error:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
The following packages will be upgraded:
  alsa-ucm-conf apport apport-gtk code curl gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-glib-2.0 gjs gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-common libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0g
  libnautilus-extension1a linux-libc-dev nautilus nautilus-data openssh-client python3-apport
  python3-problem-report python3-update-manager teamviewer update-manager update-manager-core
25 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/82.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 30.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'python3-pygments' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [files list file for package 'libvo-aacenc0:amd64' is missing final newline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878973/)